# Remove known password from DMG file

Tags: macos, security, password, dmg

I have a few .dmg files of which I know the password. I am easily able to mount them and view the contents. Is there any way to remove the password from the files? From what I see `hdiutil chpass` is able to change the password but I don't see a way to remove the password. Does anyone know a way?

Comment: To make matter worse, using `hdiutil chpass` to change to an empty password works but the resulting DMG can't be opened in Finder any longer (`hdiutil attach` works though).

Comment: Yep, hdiutil allows setting a blank password, which is still considered to be a password and does not remove it contrary to expected behaviour. On the other hand, Finder does not accept a blank password, and the file cannot be mounted/opened by finder. Though the good thing is that hdiutil can be used again to change that blank password to something else